# Browser Extension: Lowest possible permission to get current tabs URL

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions, chrome-web-store, browser-extension

A browser extension, I've had previously published on the Google webstore has been taken down due permissions. The reasoning was to reduce unneeded permissions - I've removed all unneeded permissions. Now only `activeTab` is used in the `manifest.json`. The updated extension still wasn't accepted with the following message:

```
Your Product violates the “Use of Permissions” section of the policy, which requires that you: 

Request access to the narrowest permissions necessary to implement your Product’s features or services. If more than one permission could be used to implement a feature, you must request those with the least access to data or functionality.

[...]

To reinstate your Product, please ensure that your Product requests and uses only those permissions that are necessary to deliver the currently stated product’s features.
```

My questions I'm hoping to get an answer to:

- Is there a simpler way to get the currently active tabs URL?
- Is there an hierarchy of permissions someone to check which one's are considered higher value?

Thanks for your help

Comment: It depends on where from you need to get the current Tab URL i.e background, broswerAction, pageAction, content etc

Comment: Currently its in the popup. That's where I'm using the URL as well.

Comment: `activeTab` is a fairly basic permission. In fact the normal process to get the active tab URL from browserAction is to use `tabs` permission and  `tabs.query()`. Either there is an error in the assessment or there are other issues which is not possible to comment on without seeing the code. Was it uploaded to AMO? Where?

Comment: What does AMO stand for? There aren't any other permissions used or attempted to be accessed. The two lines from the email above are the one which were bolded - so I assume these are the issue. `Tabs` would allow me to access more data than `activeTab`, so I assume ranking is lower. Is that correct? I wonder too, if the assessment is incorrect maybe.

Comment: AMO = `addons.mozilla.org` You marked the question for Firefox. Didn't you submit your addon to Mozilla?. `ActiveTab` is lower than `tabs` although there is no ranking system for permissions. It is possible that your Chrome submission has been blacklisted somehow and they are blocking it regardless of the permission.

Comment: Ah, okay. Yes, it's submitted to AMO without any issues. The whole issue started when I initiated a transfer of the extension to another developer. I'm kinda clueless as my questions I send to Google are unanswered. I just get the same email back as before - which doesn't answer my questions.

Comment: Generally, add-on must request permissions that is needs to function and not more than that. It doesn't matter how powerful the permissions are.

Comment: Yes, that's not a problem. I'm requesting only one permissions and it's the lowest permission I could use for it (as far as I know). `Tabs` would be more powerful. Do you know a different way to get the current URL than using `activeTab`?

Comment: There is no problem with `activeTab` or `tabs` permission. The problem is elsewhere. There are 1000s of extensions that have  `activeTab` or `tabs` permission.

Comment: Yes, that's the issue I got reported back - the two points above. Nothing else.